# Using a template class inside a non-template class (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, generics, compilation

Here is the problem. I have two C++ classes: the first one, call it `TemplateClass`, and a second one `MyClass`, defined in this way

```cpp
template <int A, int B>
class TemplateClass { ... };

class MyClass { ... };
```

The idea is to use an instantiation of the first class as a member of the second class. The problem is that, since the first class is a template class the values of A and B must be known at compile time, this means that I cannot do something like

```cpp
class MyClass {
    TemplateClass *tc;

    MyClass(const int a, const int b) {
        this->tc = new TemplateClass<a,b>();
    } 
};
```

The only way I can do this is the declare `MyClass` as a template class as well, i.e.,

```cpp
template <int A, int B>
class TemplateClass { ... };

template <int A, int B>
class MyClass {
    TemplateClass<A,B> *tc;

    MyClass () {
        this->tc = new TemplateClass<A,B>();
    }
};
```

However, this leads to a lot of problem, first of all every methods of MyClass should be defined in the header file, resulting in a very big file.

**Is there a way to avoid this and keep MyClass a non-template class**?

Comment: Compile-time arguments must be known at compile-time. This won't work unless you can cast to e.g. a base class of all `TemplateClass`es.

Comment: @RichardCritten `TemplateClass` takes two non-type template parameters of type `int`. `TemplateClass<int, int>` is not a valid instantiation; `TemplateClass<1, 2>` would be.

Comment: Well, one way to keep `MyClass` a non-template class is to make `TemplateClass` a non-template class as well, taking its parameters in the constructor just like `MyClass` does. If you want a better advice, you'd need to take a step back and describe what problem you are trying to solve, that you believe these two classes would help with. As written, this sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: No there isn't, C++ does not work this way, fundamentally.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your class into two parts: `MyClassBase` where methods of `MyClass` that do not rely on the `TemplateClass` are defined. And second part, `MyClass` that inherits from `MyClassBase` and is template on the two parameters `A` and `B`, where remaining methods are defined.

This way only methods requiring to be templates will need be in the header.

Though, generally, the question what actually you need.

In other cases, you can write a non-template `Interface` class for your `TemplateClass` and store pointer to it.

Answer (score 0):

> **Is there a way to avoid this and keep MyClass a non-template class?**

Not really, unless the set of accepted values for `a` and `b` is rather small.
You would have to instantiate `TemplateClass` for any possible combination of `a` and `b`. If you allow any two `int`'s for `a` and `b`, this would result in 2^64 classes being instantiated which in turn would crash your compiler.

If `a` and `b` *really* need to be template parameters than you have to restrict the input space, manually instantiate the template for the values you need and during construction dynamically dispatch based on the runtime value of `a` and `b`. To use the parametrized object though, you need to introduce some form of type erasure like a base class with `virtual` functions and then store a pointer to the base class and access all your functionality through your virtual functions:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

template <int A, int B>
class TemplateClass: public Base { 
    /* Implement f() based on a and b */
};

class MyClass {
    Base *tc;

    MyClass(const int a, const int b) {
        if (a == 0 && b == 0) {
            this->tc = new TemplateClass<0, 0>();
        }
        else if (a == 0 && b == 42) {
            this->tc = new TemplateClass<0, 42>();
        }
        else { 
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid values for a and b"); 
        }
    } 

    void g() {
        // Use TemplateClass<a, b> through the interface of Base, e.g.: 
        tc->f();
    }
};
```

This is of course not pretty but depending on what you are actually trying to archive this or something similar will be required.